# How can I render to framebuffer back sides of the cube? (Invisible sides from my point of view?)

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am trying to develop volume rendering in WebGL with Three.js library. I know how to do that in pure WebGL, but i am not able to find any way in Three.js.

So..the problem...

1) How can I draw the back face of boundingbox (i have a cube) to framebuffer? I need draw only invisible sides of the cube.

2) How can I draw front face of boundingbox? (Only frontface)

Thanks a lot :-) I really dont know how to do that in Three.js...is it possible? If it is not possible, i will do it in pure WebGL..but i dont want to mix WebGL and Three.js library..i would like to have clean solution..

Thank your very much :-)

Comment: See if `renderer.setFaceCulling( THREE.CullFaceFront, THREE.FrontFaceDirectionCW );` helps you.

Comment: I tried to set that, but nothings happend. Should i set sth (some parameters) to cubegeometry or material ? Is there any complete docs of Three.js ?I havent found anything...

Comment: I have foudn the solution :
 renderer.setFaceCulling("front"); and  renderer.setFaceCulling("front");. Thanks for HELP!:-)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select front-face or back-face culling like so:

```
renderer.setFaceCulling( THREE.CullFaceFront );

renderer.setFaceCulling( THREE.CullFaceBack );
```

three.js r.55

Comment: You are right! In new version it is exactly as you have written! Thanks

Comment: To prevent confusion, please "accept" this answer by clicking on the check mark. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

Set to renderer this:

renderer.setFaceCulling("front");

OR

renderer.setFaceCulling("back");

Thanks for help to [WestLangley.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461008/westlangley)

Comment: Sorry, that is not correct. These functions do not take string arguments. See my answer.

Comment: I have tried your arguments, but it doesnt work. I have found the function, you have written there : http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/55/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer ; Documentation said, that arguments are "front", "back", "front_back" and false. I am using version 51 of Three.js. Could it be the problem?